# CallListener onCallProgressing() not always called

Tags: sinch

I noticed that onCallProcessing() callback is not always triggered on the Caller side, rather only triggering onCallEstablished() callback.

This usually happens when the callee answers very quickly the incoming call.

Could anyone advise please ? It seems that there is no guarantee that this onCallProcessing() would be triggered.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That could be the case, call progressing means that its ringin on the other side, if you i.e have automatic pickup or the caller is as you say very quick you might not get that one.

So to be sure you stop playing progress tone, make sure its stopped in call did establish also.